# Driver ethernet TP LINK TF 3200 para Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux

Mi problema radica en la compilación del driver para la tarjeta ethernet *TP Link TF 3200* para usar en una máquina con *Ubuntu 12.04*, donde tengo los archivos **compat.h**, **crc32.h**, **ethtool.h**, **mii.c**, **mii.h** y **sundance_main.c**.

... y el archivo Makefile que es el siguiente:

```
OBJS    = sundance_main.o mii.o
TARGET  = sundance.o
MAPPING_MODE= -DUSE_IO_OPS

KernelVersion            := 4.4.0-67-generic
KernelBuildDir           := /lib/modules/4.4.0-67-generic/build
kernelMisc               := /lib/modules/4.4.0-67-generic/kernel/drivers/net/
kernelExtension          := $(echo 4.4.0-67-generic) | sed -ne 's/^2\.[567]\..*/k/p')o
kernelFlag26             := kernel2$(echo 4.4.0-67-generic | sed -ne 's/^2\.[6]\..*/6/p')x

EXTRA_CFLAGS+=$(MAPPING_MODE)
all:
$(MAKE) -C $(KernelBuildDir) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

#install:
#   install -m 644 -c sundance.$(kernelExtension) $(kernelMisc)

sundance-objs:=$(OBJS)
obj-m+=$(TARGET)

#clean:
#   rm -f *.o *.ko *~ core* .dep* .*.d .*.cmd *.mod.c *.a *.s .*.flags
```

Después de hacer `sudo make`, tengo el siguiente error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-67-generic/build SUBDIRS= modules
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-67-generic'
make[2]: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo 
 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl',
 necesario para 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/../../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'. Alto.
arch/x86/Makefile:199: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'archheaders'
make[1]: *** [archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-67-generic'
Makefile:14: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'all'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay unas cuantas preguntas similares en la vasta internet:

[Can't access the open /arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29951663)

En la respuesta aceptada, además de comprobar por nosotros mismos si dicho archivo

> `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-67-generic/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl`

existe realmente y se puede leer para todo el mundo, recomiendan bajar los fuentes *vanilla* del kernel, preferiblemente de una versión LTS.

**NOTA**

Acabo de recordar una cosa. El kernel dejó de soportar la arquitectura `i386` en la versión **3.8**, y tu estás compilando con la versión 4.4. En mi propia versión 4.8, dicho archivo **tampoco** está presente.

Si estoy en lo cierto, los drivers que intentas compilar **son para 32 bits**, y **no podrás** hacerlo para el kernel que tienes. No tiene solución.

Tendrás que bajarte e instalar un kernel mas antiguo, anterior al 3.8. O prescindir del driver. O buscar una versión mas reciente del *susodicho* driver.